# Web keyword search and counter

Tags: javascript, java, python

I am new to programming (Java) but I had an idea. An example of this would be with dogs, like the following:

Search "Cutest Dogs"

Follow the first link.

Search the site for keywords, like "Terrier" or "Bulldog" (There would be more, like 2,000+)

Follow the second link.

Search the site for keywords.

It does that for a few google pages.

Compile a list with the frequency of each keyword e.g.

Terrier-219 matches

Bulldog-183 matches

and so on.

How would I go about this, what language would I need to write it in, and how difficult would it be for me to do (as previously mentioned, a beginner)?

Comment: That's very close to a program that goes through every part of a mailing list, indexing entries and searching through them based on word frequence, included in the excellent *Programming Erlang* by Armstrong: https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/808814.Programming_Erlang Erlang is neither javascript, java nor python, but it's a nice language with concepts you could transfer to other languages later, and that book is very good.

Answer (score 0):

Using Python, you could use the library [requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/) to easily download the content of an HTML webpage and then use regex or string search functions (such as the [`str.count`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.count) method) to find your keywords. I think it would be fairly simple to set up, some example code would be:

```
import requests
html = requests.get(url).content
html.count('Terrier')
```

That example would give you code for counting the number of times the string 'Terrier' appears in the webpage specified by whichever `url` you pass to the function. You could also use the requests library to scrape the content of [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=cutest%20dogs) Google results webpage for "cutest dogs" and then pull out each link you want to follow and search. To find the links to webpages, you can use a library like [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) to find the links on the page and then to follow their URL. An example of finding the links could be something like:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html) # where html is the result of downloading the html for a webpage, similar to the code above
links = soup.find_all('a')
```

To create your frequency table, you can use the Python [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict) type to store a table where the keys are your search strings and the values are the frequencies. Here's an example of incrementing the frequency count for a specific string

```
frequencies = {'Terrier': 0}
frequencies['Terrier'] += html.count('Terrier)
```